# Django iterate through a list of webpages

Tags: django

Hi I'm relatively new to python and DJANGO and was wondering if there was a way to load a webpage from a currently loaded webpage after a time delay

For example i have 5 or 6 graphs/charts on separate pages within my django project and want them to be displayed for 5-10 seconds then switch to the next one

I may be just missing something simple here but any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your title appears to refer to a completely different question.

Comment: hi now that i reread my example it isn't a very good one. ill edit it with a better one sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect them to submit the form within 30 seconds then a [meta-refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) is quite a simple way to achieve that.

Otherwise you can use a javascript redirect that fires after a delay. The redirect would check that no action (such as filling out the fields) has been performed during the delay. Something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (noChange) {
        window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
    }
}, 30 * 1000);
```

Comment: thanks this worked almost exactly the way i needed it to

Answer (score 1):

You should use javascript to do that:

```
$(function(){
 setTimeout(checkUserStatus, 30000);
})

function checkUserStatus(){
    //Code to check if user hit/click anything
    //if yes clear TimeInterval and do the operation
    //If no clear Time Interval and redirect to home page
}
```